# Stuck in passing and catching kwargs

Tags: python

Python 3.5.2

Could you help me understand how parameters are transmitted to the method.

Just in case: this is Django but the question seems to be just about Python.

As far as I can catch from the Django's documentation: if I pass form_kwargs to a formset like this, several forms will be created. And in the form I expect to catch the parameter in **kwargs.

```
class MyArticleForm(ArticleForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


formset = ArticleFormSet(form_kwargs={'user': user})
```

Well, this is not working:

```
  File "/home/michael/workspace/formsets/general/forms.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
KeyError: 'user'
```

If I step in the debugger: kwargs definitely doesn't contain any 'user'. And args is an empty tuple.

But this works:

```
class MyArticleForm(ArticleForm):
    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
         pass
```

And this works:

```
class MyArticleForm(ArticleForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
         pass
```

Well, I can't understand how can I catch this parameter in using kwargs?

///////////
ADDED LATER

```
ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(MyArticleForm)

def formset_factory(form, formset=BaseFormSet, extra=1, can_order=False,
                    can_delete=False, max_num=None, validate_max=False,
                    min_num=None, validate_min=False):
    pass

class BaseFormSet(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                 initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, form_kwargs=None):
    ...
    self.form_kwargs = form_kwargs or {}
    ....
```

Comment: How are you instantiating MyArticleForm? Whether it is you or Django doing it under the hood, it needs something like `form = MyArticleForm(user='username')` otherwise the user argument is null. If this might be the case sometimes, you need to surround `self.user = ...` in a try catch excepting `KeyError`.

Comment: karimtabet, MyArticleForm is instantiated by Django. I tried to demonstrate it (added to the end of the initial post).

Comment: @Michael Are you using `django.forms.formset_factory` or the one you defined?

Comment: Yes. ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(MyArticleForm)

Comment: This is relevant Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms   I just tried to model it. The example seemed pretty straightforward.

Comment: What version of Django are you on?

Comment: Moses Koledoye, Django 1.10.1,

Comment: The last update makes a little confusing. Were those functions redefined? Can you please show what you have all in one code block

Comment: Moses Koledoye, in one block will be hard. Maybe this? Kifsif@bitbucket.org/Kifsif/formsets.git Files to have a look at: general.forms.py and general.views.py.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124398/discussion-between-moses-koledoye-and-michael).